# Jquery Conditional dropdown in a Mobile App

Tags: javascript, jquery, hybrid-mobile-app, onsen-ui

I'm integrating a conditional drop down using Jquery however I'm having some issues.

1. I need the default value on = 1.
2. When opening different pages of the mobile app and then returning to home page the drop down doesn't work until you exit the app and then open it again.

The code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    #selMethod {
        display: none;
    }
    .header {
        background-color: #ff0000;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  </style>

  <title></title>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
    $("select").change(function () {
    var str = "";

    str = parseInt($("select option:selected").val());

        if(str == 1){
          $("#selMethod").show();
          $("#sel0").show();
        } else if(str >= 1){
         $("#selMethod").show();
         for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
             $("#sel" + i).hide();
         str = str - 1;

         $("#sel" + str).show();
        }
      else
          $("#selMethod").hide();
});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="homeop">
    <label for="main">Choose An Option: <span class="req">*</span></label>
    <select class="cat_dropdown" id="cat_dropdown" name="cat_dropdown">
        <option value="0">-- Please select --</option>
        <option value="1" selected>Search By Address</option>
        <option value="2">Restaurant Name</option>
        <option value="3">Cuisine</option>
        <option value="4">Food</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="selMethod">
    <div id="selOptions">
        <div id="selInfo">
            <div id="sel0" class="homeselinfo">
                   <h4 class="trn" data-trn-key="enter_your_location">Enter your location</h4>

                   <section class="field-section">
                     <input id="s" value="" type="text" class="text-input text-input--underbar trn" ng-model="text" placeholder="Street Address,City,State" data-trn-key="home_search_placeholder" 
                     style="display: block; width: 100%">
                   </section>

                   <div class="padtop25">
                   <button class="button button--quiet green" onclick="getCurrentLocation();">
                   <ons-icon icon="fa-location-arrow"></ons-icon>
                   <span class="trn" data-trn-key="use_my_location">Use my current location</span>
                   </button>       
                   </div>

                    <button class="button green-btn button--large" onclick="searchMerchant();">
                      <span class="trn" data-trn-key="search_restaurant">Search Restaurant</span>             
                      <div class="search-btn"><ons-icon icon="fa-chevron-right"></ons-icon></div>
                   </button>
            </div>

            <div id="sel1" class="homeselinfo">

                   <h4 class="trn" data-trn-key="enter_your_location">Find Restaurant by Name</h4>

                   <section class="field-section">
                     <input id="s" value="" type="text" class="text-input text-input--underbar trn" ng-model="text" placeholder="Restaurant Name" data-trn-key="home_search_placeholder" 
                     style="display: block; width: 100%">
                   </section>

                    <button class="button green-btn button--large" onclick="searchMerchant();">
                      <span class="trn" data-trn-key="search_restaurant">Search Restaurant</span>             
                      <div class="search-btn"><ons-icon icon="fa-chevron-right"></ons-icon></div>
                   </button>

            </div>

            <div id="sel2" class="homeselinfo">
                <p>selMENT INFO OPTION 3</p>
            </div>

            <div id="sel3" class="homeselinfo">
                <p>selMENT INFO OPTION 3333</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace the whole script to resolve the issue and now it's working.

```
<style type="text/css">
div.method_options {
  display: none;
}
#tr_A {
    display:block;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#id_application_method').on('change', function() {

    $('div.method_options').hide();
    $('#tr_' + $(this).val()).show();

  });

});

</script>
```